# Convert C# code to vb.net issue (Windows RT)

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to implements sound feature to a Windows RT app in vb.net with SharpDX, and I need to convert this class to vb.net:

```
using SharpDX.IO;
using SharpDX.Multimedia;
using SharpDX.XAudio2;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace PlayWaveRT {
public class WaveManager {
    private XAudio2 xAudio;
    private List<Wave> waves = new List<Wave>();

    public WaveManager() {
        xAudio = new XAudio2();
        var mastering = new MasteringVoice(xAudio);
        mastering.SetVolume(1, 0);
        xAudio.StartEngine();
    }

    public void LoadWave(string path, string key) {
        var buffer = GetBuffer(path);
        waves.Add(new Wave { Buffer = buffer, Key = key });
    }

    public void PlayWave(string key) {
        var wave = waves.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == key);
        if (wave != null) {
            var voice = new SourceVoice(xAudio, wave.Buffer.WaveFormat, true);
            voice.SubmitSourceBuffer(wave.Buffer, wave.Buffer.DecodedPacketsInfo);
            voice.Start();
        }
    }

    private AudioBufferAndMetaData GetBuffer(string soundfile) {
        var nativefilestream = new NativeFileStream(soundfile, NativeFileMode.Open, NativeFileAccess.Read, NativeFileShare.Read);
        var soundstream = new SoundStream(nativefilestream);
        var buffer = new AudioBufferAndMetaData {
            Stream = soundstream.ToDataStream(),
            AudioBytes = (int)soundstream.Length,
            Flags = BufferFlags.EndOfStream,
            WaveFormat = soundstream.Format,
            DecodedPacketsInfo = soundstream.DecodedPacketsInfo
        };
        return buffer;
    }

    private sealed class AudioBufferAndMetaData : AudioBuffer {
        public WaveFormat WaveFormat { get; set; }
        public uint[] DecodedPacketsInfo { get; set; }
    }

    private class Wave {
        public AudioBufferAndMetaData Buffer { get; set; }
        public string Key { get; set; }
    }
}
}
```

This is what I've done:

```
Imports SharpDX.IO
Imports SharpDX.Multimedia
Imports SharpDX.XAudio2
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq

Namespace PlayWaveRT

Public Class WaveManager

    Private xAudio As XAudio2
    Private waves As New List(Of Wave)()

    Public Sub New()
        xAudio = New XAudio2()
        Dim mastering = New MasteringVoice(xAudio)
        mastering.SetVolume(1, 0)
        xAudio.StartEngine()
    End Sub

    Public Sub LoadWave(path As String, key1 As String)
        Dim buffer1 = GetBuffer(path)
        Dim wave As New Wave()
        wave.Buffer = buffer1
        wave.Key = key1
    End Sub

    Public Sub PlayWave(key1 As String)
        Dim wave = waves.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Key = key1)
        If wave IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim voice = New SourceVoice(xAudio, wave.Buffer.WaveFormat, True)
            voice.SubmitSourceBuffer(wave.Buffer, wave.Buffer.DecodedPacketsInfo)
            voice.Start()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Function GetBuffer(soundfile As String) As AudioBufferAndMetaData
        Dim nativefilestream = New NativeFileStream(soundfile, NativeFileMode.Open, NativeFileAccess.Read,  NativeFileShare.Read)
        Dim soundstream = New SoundStream(nativefilestream)
        Dim buffer = New AudioBufferAndMetaData()
        buffer.Stream = soundstream.ToDataStream()
        buffer.AudioBytes = CInt(soundstream.Length)
        buffer.Flags = BufferFlags.EndOfStream
        buffer.WaveFormat = soundstream.Format
        buffer.DecodedPacketsInfo = soundstream.DecodedPacketsInfo
        Return buffer
    End Function

    Private Class AudioBufferAndMetaData
        Inherits AudioBuffer

        Private m_WaveFormat As WaveFormat
        Private m_DecodedPacketsInfo As UInteger()

        Public Property WaveFormat As WaveFormat
            Get
                Return m_WaveFormat
            End Get
            Set(value As WaveFormat)
                m_WaveFormat = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property DecodedPacketsInfo As UInteger()
            Get
                Return m_DecodedPacketsInfo
            End Get
            Set(value As UInteger())
                m_DecodedPacketsInfo = value
            End Set
        End Property

    End Class

    Private Class Wave
        Private m_Buffer As AudioBufferAndMetaData
        Private m_Key As String

        Public Property Buffer As AudioBufferAndMetaData
            Get
                Return m_Buffer
            End Get
            Set(value As AudioBufferAndMetaData)
                m_Buffer = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property Key As String
            Get
                Return m_Key
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                m_Key = value
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class

End Class

End Namespace
```

I have no compilator errors, but the code isn't working and I don't know where's the problem.

I've imported to my project SharpDX.dll and SharpDX.XAudio2.dll

This is how I usage this class in my Project:

```
Imports The_Game_of_15.PlayWaveRT
Public NotInheritable Class SelectPage
Inherits Page

Private waveManager As New WaveManager()

Protected Overrides Sub OnNavigatedTo(e As Navigation.NavigationEventArgs)
    ..........
    ..........
    waveManager.LoadWave("select.wav", "select")
End Sub

Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    waveManager.PlayWave("select")
End Sub

End Class
```

I can compile the project with no errors, but no sound it's played when I click the button. Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did the C# version work before you ported it across to VB?

Comment: Yes it's works. Anyway I've resolved the problem. Thanks to ken2k and DonA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VB.Net inline:

```
Public Sub LoadWave(path As String, key1 As String)
    Dim buffer1 = GetBuffer(path)
    waves.Add(New Wave With {.Buffer = buffer,.Key = key})
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You forget to `Add` your element in the list:

C#

```
waves.Add(new Wave { Buffer = buffer, Key = key });
```

VB.Net

```
Dim wave As New Wave()
wave.Buffer = buffer1
wave.Key = key1
```

That being said, it's easy to follow in the debugger...

Comment: That's was the problem. Now it's working, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

developerFusion C#<->VB.net [complete](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/?batchId=303bb9a2-7d42-4870-9ea5-551ac24eefaa)

```
Imports SharpDX.IO
Imports SharpDX.Multimedia
Imports SharpDX.XAudio2
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq

Namespace PlayWaveRT
    Public Class WaveManager
        Private xAudio As XAudio2
        Private waves As New List(Of Wave)()

        Public Sub New()
            xAudio = New XAudio2()
            Dim mastering = New MasteringVoice(xAudio)
            mastering.SetVolume(1, 0)
            xAudio.StartEngine()
        End Sub

        Public Sub LoadWave(path As String, key As String)
            Dim buffer = GetBuffer(path)
            waves.Add(New Wave() With { _
                Key .Buffer = buffer, _
                Key .Key = key _
            })
        End Sub

        Public Sub PlayWave(key As String)
            Dim wave = waves.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Key = key)
            If wave IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim voice = New SourceVoice(xAudio, wave.Buffer.WaveFormat, True)
                voice.SubmitSourceBuffer(wave.Buffer, wave.Buffer.DecodedPacketsInfo)
                voice.Start()
            End If
        End Sub

        Private Function GetBuffer(soundfile As String) As AudioBufferAndMetaData
            Dim nativefilestream = New NativeFileStream(soundfile, NativeFileMode.Open, NativeFileAccess.Read, NativeFileShare.Read)
            Dim soundstream = New SoundStream(nativefilestream)
            Dim buffer = New AudioBufferAndMetaData() With { _
                Key .Stream = soundstream.ToDataStream(), _
                Key .AudioBytes = CInt(soundstream.Length), _
                Key .Flags = BufferFlags.EndOfStream, _
                Key .WaveFormat = soundstream.Format, _
                Key .DecodedPacketsInfo = soundstream.DecodedPacketsInfo _
            }
            Return buffer
        End Function

        Private NotInheritable Class AudioBufferAndMetaData
            Inherits AudioBuffer
            Public Property WaveFormat() As WaveFormat
                Get
                    Return m_WaveFormat
                End Get
                Set
                    m_WaveFormat = Value
                End Set
            End Property
            Private m_WaveFormat As WaveFormat
            Public Property DecodedPacketsInfo() As UInteger()
                Get
                    Return m_DecodedPacketsInfo
                End Get
                Set
                    m_DecodedPacketsInfo = Value
                End Set
            End Property
            Private m_DecodedPacketsInfo As UInteger()
        End Class

        Private Class Wave
            Public Property Buffer() As AudioBufferAndMetaData
                Get
                    Return m_Buffer
                End Get
                Set
                    m_Buffer = Value
                End Set
            End Property
            Private m_Buffer As AudioBufferAndMetaData
            Public Property Key() As String
                Get
                    Return m_Key
                End Get
                Set
                    m_Key = Value
                End Set
            End Property
            Private m_Key As String
        End Class
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: Most of times automatic converters like developerFusion not work properly. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I also wrote a blog post on the VB Team Blog about how to play audio in Win8.1/WP8.1 apps using SharpDX:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2014/06/15/vb-universal-app-part-4-using-sharpdx-for-sound-effects-with-ioc-and-linkedfiles.aspx